# How to copy all items from a nested list to an empty nested list using for loops

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am currently trying to add all the items in a nested list, such as this one `[['apple','orange','banana'],['jaguar','bear','octopus'],['spruce','pine','birch']]`, to an empty list of the same length, `[ [] [] [] ]`.
For loops would be the best option I believe.

I cannot figure out where to start. I become very confused when working with nested lists and for loops

Answer (score 1):

probably you are searching how to do it with basic for loop:

```
data = [['apple','orange','banana'],['jaguar','bear','octopus'],['spruce','pine','birch']]
copy_data = [ [],[],[] ]

n = len(data)
for i in range(n):
    copy_data[i] = data[i]

print (copy_data)
```

output:

```
[['apple', 'orange', 'banana'], ['jaguar', 'bear', 'octopus'], ['spruce', 'pine', 'birch']]
```

> Iterate over the list using for loop:
>
> -Fist get the size of list
>
> -Then iterate using for loop from 0 to len(data)
>
> -In each iteration access iTh element from list data and add element to iTh element of list copy_data

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend `deepcopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy
x = [['apple', 'orange', 'banana'], ['jaguar', 'bear', 'octopus'], ['spruce', 'pine', 'birch']]
y = deepcopy(x)
print(x)
print(y)
```

These lists (`x` & `y`) are now completely different references.